# Dart Widget created based on a list always uses initState of other Widget in List

Tags: flutter, list, dart

The children of my column are created with the data of a List of Maps. `

```
children: [for (var alarm in alarmDataList) AlarmWidget(alarmData: alarm)],
```

`I do some changes to my alarms on another Screen. Before that, I delete the according `alarmData`.

To do that, I have a `deleteAlarmDataList` function which I call to delete an element of the List. To update my Screen, I call Setstate.`

```
void deleteAlarmDataList (Map alarm) {
  alarmDataList.removeWhere((element) => element.hashCode == alarm.hashCode);
  setState(() { alarmDataList; });
}
```

`Afterwards I call my `addAlarmDataList` function, which adds a Map to the List `alarmData` and sorts the Data. Afterwards the `alarmDataList` gets updated.`

```
  void addAlarmDataList (Map alarm) {
    if(alarm['time'] != 'noAdd') setState(() alarmDataList.add(alarm);});
    setState(() {alarmDataList.sort((a, b) => a['time'].compareTo(b['time']));});
   }
```

`My problem is, that I have a function which gets called in the initState of the class `AlarmWidget` which needs to be executed so all information is shown correctly. Unfortunately, in the process of the `addAlarmDataList` function, the initState of the last index of the `alarmDataList` is called, instead of the one I added. Also the initState is called after the whole `addAlarmDataList` function and not after the if clause.

I want the initState of the Widget with the latest added `AlarmData` to be called. I have tried to insert the insert the new Map at index 0, but this didn't help.

```
if(alarm['time'] != 'noAdd') setState(() {alarmDataList.insert(0, alarm);});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not sure this will solve all your issue.  let me help to bring you on track.

when you call `setState`, the `build` method will be re-executed.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
....
}
```

thats why, everytime you call the `setState` all widget inside the build method will be executed.

and thats caused **the last index of the `alarmDataList` is called** on  your widget.

Comment: I guess I am confused there. The first line of code is in the according `build` method. Shouldn't the `initState` of all entries of my `alarmDataList` be called then? Why only the last?

Comment: I got it: First I thought, you were talking about the `build` where I create the widgets and not of the `build` of the widget itself. After I called the function there, everything worked as expected